# eclipse: No "Maven" entry for Windows / Preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I had eclipse Juno running; I decided to upgrade to eclipse Kepler.  I only had Java 1.6, so I downloaded and installed java 1.7, and changed my JAVA_HOME.  I downloaded and unpacked Kepler and pointed it at my existing workspace.

I have two questions; First, when I click on "Window / Preferences", there is no entry for "Maven" on the left of the dialog.  I shut down and rebooted the machine after I changed JAVA_HOME to ensure that didn't cause this.

I checked the list of installed plugins, and it lists m2e (v1.4).

Second, I am getting an error message "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration".  There are a double-handful of sites indicating what to do about this, including the m2e's wiki pages, but over half the suggestions don't look reasonable, the wiki doesn't spell out what to do for its recommended solution, assuming you know, and the one that looked most promising to me involves using "Windows / Preferences / Maven".

So I'm most interested in the answer to the first question; if you have hints to offer on the second, I'm all ears...

Comment: Have you tried to start Eclipse with the `-clean` switch?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had not.  I just did, and it did not change anything on either problem.

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall (of the plugin)?

Comment: (sigh) the plugin does not appear under the "installed software" tab, so I cannot uninstall it with the uninstall button.  It does appear under the "plugin" tab.  I'm searching the web for ways to eliminate it by deleting files somewhere, I assume it is left over from the Juno installation I was using.

Comment: Just delete the jars from the **plugins** directory and install it again from Marketplace.

Comment: Are you on Windows ? and what version of OS are you running this on ?

Comment: Windows 7, Home Premium 64-bit, SP1

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things you can try:

- Start Eclipse with the `-clean` switch
- Uninstall / reinstall the plugin
- Delete the plugin's files physically from the **plugins** folder and install it again from the Marketplace

If all else fails you can just get a fresh installation of Eclipse and reinstall your old plugins manually. There are some of them which won't work in a newer version of Eclipse (I remember for example that I had to install WindowBuilder all over again after an Eclipse version switch).

Comment: Reasonable things to try, thanks -- do you know if I have to create a new workspace, or can I point to a workspace created in Juno from a Kepler installation?

Comment: You can try a new workspace since in your current one there is a directory named `.metadata` and it can hold various configurations for your plugins.

Comment: aha -- so my old workspace would hold configuration data for plugins that aren't installed (yet).  Hmmm -- might explain weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this came about by installing a new version of eclipse but pointing it at a workspace for the previous version.  I have been told that there is metadata attached to a workspace that has to do with plugins; this would be bound to cause problems for a version that didn't have the plugins.  I eliminated the new install, installed it again, created a new workspace, and imported-with-copy the project I wanted, that has eliminated the error.  I will pursue that further.

Thanks to Adam Arold who pointed out the metadata issue.