# lost maven after eclipse update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I use a from customer installed eclipse with different maven projects:
[image]
[image]

After the last (automatically) update

- I don't see: Window->Preferences->Maven
- I don't see menu point: Run As->Maven buid
- I can not create a maven project

In ~/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.log I find the following error message:

```
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.apt.core 4 0 2022-09-20 19:59:56.249
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.m2e.apt.core [635]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="2.0.3.20220904-1703"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.m2e.core [640]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt; bundle-version="2.0.1.20220901-1459"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [645]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="2.0.3.20220904-1703"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1852)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
...
```

In [eclipse: No "Maven" entry for Windows / Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424168/eclipse-no-maven-entry-for-windows-preferences) I found the hints from Adam Arold:

- Start Eclipse with the -clean switch
- Uninstall / reinstall the plugin
- Delete the plugin's files physically from the plugins folder and install it again from the Marketplace

But I can not deinstall or update the maven plugin:
[image]

[image]

How can I activate the maven preferences in my eclipse? I don't want to install an old eclipse version.

Thank you for yor hints,
Ann

Comment: This is saying the maven plug-ins require at least Java 17 to run. Many Eclipse downloads include a suitable Java 17 but if you are using your own Java it will have to be updated to Java 17 (or later)

Comment: What greg-449 says. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73731534/6505250